# Is there an equivalent to debounce in WebFlux?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a webflux that gets data from a stream of events, but I want it to end up in a more or less stable state (i.e. the events stop flowing for a few milliseconds) sort of like the debounce operator in RxJS.

I can't seem to find anything like that in the API though.

Answer (score 0):

The webflux equivalent is the bufferTimeout method

```
 .bufferTimeout(20, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
```

The advantage of it is you get all the events not just the last one which is what `debounce` does as a list.